# IntelliJ - New Data Source with Amazon RDS MySQL Database (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a data source on IntelliJ to connect with my MySQL database on Amazon RDS like that:

[image]

But it fails. I am able to connect to my database using `application.properties` and adding `cloud.aws.region.static=eu-central-1`. Without the addition of the region, it fails to connect. My guess is that the data source probably needs something similar. My goal is to generate POJOs from the database into the Spring Boot application and that's why I need a data source from my database. In addition,I am  connecting through MySQL Workbench with the Amazon RDS with no issues.

The error on IntelliJ

[image]

Comment: So what's the error you get? Do you have a stacktrace or logs?

Comment: I just added the error know, it's mostly a connection error.

Comment: I am also facing same problem did you find solution to it ??

Comment: @KarriAravind Sorry it's been a long time but I don't believe I solved since then. Haven't tried again something similar.

Comment: @ManolisPap I solved it , It has nothing to do with intel j and every thing is controlled by EC2 , security groups inbound rules